# issue with HttpURLConnection OutputStream

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
String urlString = API_URL + "/checkins/add";  
            String inputdata = "v=20111111"+"&venueId="+venueid+"&broadcast="+broadcast+"&oauth_token="+mAccessToken;  
            String content="";  
            try {  
                URL url = new URL( urlString );
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setDoOutput( true ); 
                con.connect();  

                Log.v("RESPONSE MESSAGE", con.getResponseMessage());

                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());  
                out.write(inputdata);  
                out.flush();
```

and I am getting an error:

```
Exception: OutputStream unavailable because request headers have already been sent!
```

why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are calling `con.getResponseMessage()` in your log statement the http message has to get sent and the response read. So by this time the its to late to add a request body using the `OutputStream`. Just move the log message after writing the input data and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

### HTTP Methods

**HttpURLConnection** uses the **`GET`** method by default. It will use **`POST`** if **`setDoOutput(true)`** has been called. Other HTTP methods (`OPTIONS`, `HEAD`, `PUT`, `DELETE` and `TRACE`) can be used with **`setRequestMethod(String)`**.

This is the reason for getting the exception.

Comment: None of this 'is the reason for getting this exception', or indeed any exception. Downvote.

Comment: @EJP: Here `con.setRequestMethod("POST");` and `con.setDoOutput( true );` are trying to set the `POST` method.

Comment: Of course, but it still isn't 'the reason for the exception'.